# intel HD graphics with integrated tv tuner

Tags: laptop, integrated-graphics, tuner-card

I have a new Dell laptop with Intel HD graphics and an integrated TV tuner.

How can I use this TV tuner? Should I install third party software for using it or just configure something? I tried to google it but couldn't find anything.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is very simple!**

1. Open Dell's offical site: [dell.com](http://www.dell.com/)
2. Go to the [Drivers/Downloads page](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/) (you can find it on the site footer)
3. Enter the details of your model, or you can type in your service tag (found on the underneath of your laptop)
4. When the model is chosen, pick the operating system used and submit search.
5. In the list of available drivers/software, toggle "Video", and you will see "*AverMedia*" or something similar; this is your TV Tuner's driver/software.

Comment: You should also try plugging in a cable and configuring it with Windows Media Center (assuming you are running Vista or 7)--if the drivers are already installed, you may not need Dell's software to use it.

Comment: nevermind, after a long research, I've found that the card is type of "AVerMedia A338 Hybrid Analog/ATSC." this card uses ATSC which isn't supported at my country (Israel), here they are using PAL. maybe simple analog signal will be able to received..